# XSLT Получение Min Max колонки таблицы

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Есть таблица, пару колонок, нужно с помощью XSLT 1.0 в браузере показать таблицу, а снизу максимальное и минимальное значение столбца. Как это сделать без использования сортировок? По гуглив только такой способ нашёл...

Comment: Какая версия xslt? В 2.0 есть функции max/min. Судя по тэгу html планируется делать трансформацию в браузере?

Comment: версия 1.0, в браузере должна появиться табличка, а снизу максимальное и минимальное значение столбца

Comment: Браузеры очень плохо поддерживают xslt. Делайте трансформацию на сервере.

Comment: Ну так всё просто, к сожалению :( а что насчёт поиска мин, макс? Спасибо

Comment: Найти мин и макс на сервере, на клиента передать уже готовые значения.